# Default values of a multiselect input in widget options using widget.xml

Tags: magento-1.9, multiselect-attribute, widget

I have this option in my widget.xml:

```
<animation_effects>
                <label>Effects</label>
                <visible>1</visible>
                <required>0</required>
                <type>multiselect</type>
                <source_model>Test_MyModule_Model_System_Config_Source_Ease</source_model>
                <values>fade scale</values>
</animation_effects>
```

How can I set default values of this multiselect input of my widget ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I remember correctly multiselect values are stored comma separated. Have you tried `<value>opt1,opt2</value>` ?